# How can i get the url of the filterable attribute in layered navigation?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

As we know the filterable attributes on the layered navigation has certain url that magento creates on click which filters the product list.
Let me explain my issue by giving an example. Let's say i have an attribute city which is filterable.Now the city attribute has options like **"melbourne","sydney",etc**.When I click on **melbourne** it redirects to url like

> http://Your_Base_Url/Category/filter/city/melbourne.html

Same way if there are multiple attributes Magento manages the url like that.So what I want is i have a seperate dropdown where there is listed all the options for city when i click that i have to filter the products of that category.
So I am thinking if i can generate the url same as magento creates for the layered navigation i could get my work done.

So i was hoping if someone could help me on this.I have tried to trace how the layered navigation is working but i couldn't implement that way of generating urls in my case.So any help on this is appreciable.

Regards,

aton

Comment: Why you need a separate dropdown for that ? you can add it as a attribute. And you can change the look and feel from the specific phtml files.

Comment: Yes i managed as attribute but i want a dropdown on category header where you can filter by attribute.Did you get me?

Comment: share your site link

Comment: I am doing it on my local machine, I am trying it and i think i am almost there.